# D3js : data update is not updating right objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to build a horizontal calendar timeline using d3.js. Main goal is to highlight holidays and vacations of user.

http://jsbin.com/ceperavu/2/edit?css,js,output

- I first rect from 'start' date to 'end' date.
- Then append text.
- highlight the rect which match the data from `vacations`
- **but it highlights always the first 'n' rect.**

  ```
  var width = 650;
  var height = 450;
  var date = {start: '02/24/2014', end: '03/17/2014'};
  var day = d3.time.format("%d");
  var vacations = ['02/25/2014', '02/28/2014', '03/05/2014', '03/14/2014'];
  var cell = {width: 20, height: 20};
  var format = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y");

  var chart = d3.select("body")
                .append('svg:svg')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height)
                .attr('class', 'chart');



  var days = chart
      .selectAll(".day")
      .data(function(d) { return d3.time.days(new Date(date.start), new Date(date.end)); })
      .enter()
      .append('svg:g');

  //add rect
      days.append('svg:rect')
        .attr('width', cell.width)
        .attr('height', cell.height)
        .attr('x', function(d, i){ 
          var day = d3.time.format("%d"); 
          // console.log(day(d)); 
          return i * cell.width; })
        .attr('class', 'day')
        .append('title')
          .text(function(d){return format(d);})
        .datum(format);

  //add text
      days.append('svg:text')
        .attr('width', cell.width)
        .attr('height', cell.height)
        .attr('x', function(d, i){
          return i * cell.width + cell.width/4; 
        })
        .attr('y', 14)
        // .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
        // .style('dominant-baseline', 'central')
        .text( function(d) { var day = d3.time.format("%d");return day(d); });

  //highlight holidays
  d3.selectAll('rect.day').data(vacations).attr('class', 'holiday');
  ```

Is this wrong `d3.selectAll('rect.day').data(vacations).attr('class', 'holiday');` ?

Edit: format and additional details.

Answer (score 3):

I have changed the input data a bit so that you can compare apples to apples and also used a helper function from jquery. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FrsG/) is the result. Hope this helps.

```
days.selectAll('rect.day')
    .attr('class', function (d) {
        return  ($.inArray(d.getTime(), vacations))  > -1 ? 'holiday' : 'day';
    });
```

Comment: To clarify: The original code was replacing the data about the dates with data about vacations; without a key function, the new data was just being assigned from the beginning.  @FernOfTheAndes' code grabs all the rectangles and styles them if their date matches a vacation day.  You could alternately use a [d3 filter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) instead of doing the check within the attribute method call, but the end effect would be the same.  Filters are preferred if you're going to set multiple attributes or styles based on the same filter criteria.

Comment: Also, if you don't already have JQuery on your page, you can use `vacations.indexOf[d.getTime] > -1`.  It [doesn't work in IE8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), but neither does your SVG graphics.

Comment: For comparison, the fiddle using filter format: http://jsfiddle.net/3FrsG/1/, and using the standard Javascript method instead of JQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/3FrsG/2/

Comment: @AmeliaBR It is so good to hear from you...and in style, as usual. I up-voted your comments...like the d3 filter option and the standard Javascript date comparison.

Comment: @AmeliaBR - Can you say me how this thing works? if `vacations.indexOf[d.getTime] > -1`. I'm totally confused on this part every time and i couldn't get a good explanation. Will be very much helpful if you say. +1 vote :)

Comment: @UnknownUser First, I made a few typos, it should be round brackets like `()`, not hard brackets `[]`, and there should also be `()` after `getTime`.  The `.indexOf` method (and also the JQuery method from the main post) looks through an array for an entry that is equals (`===`) to the value you pass in (`d.getTime`).  If it finds a match, it returns the index of the first match, which will be a number 0 or greater.  If it doesn't find a match, it returns -1.  So `vacations.indexOf(d.getTime()) > -1` returns `true` if the array `vacations` contains a match for `d.getTime()`.

Comment: I should mention that it only works because the vacations array has been modified to contain timestamp values that will match the results of `getTime()`.  @FernOfTheAndes's code does this in the original data array, but you could also use a map function:  `var vacationsAsTimestamp = vacations.map(function(dateString){ return new Date(dateString).getTime();} );` [Live version](http://jsfiddle.net/3FrsG/3/)

Answer (score -1):

Here's the [<kbd>**Fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/QVXdc/).

Problem was with this code near the `days` variable.

```
var days = chart.selectAll(".day")
    .data(function(d) { return d3.time.days(new Date(date.start), new Date(date.end)); })
        .enter()
        .append('svg:g')
    .attr('class', 'day');
```

**Earlier it was like this.**

```
var days = chart
.selectAll(".day")
    .data(function(d) { return d3.time.days(new Date(date.start), new Date(date.end)); })
        .enter()
        .append('svg:g')
    .attr('class', 'day');
```

Please check if it helps.

Comment: I don't see any change except for newline remove on first line. I does not solve the main issue of highlighting dates listed `vacations` variable

Comment: You wanted to highlight the vacation days?

Comment: Yes. I want to highlight the vacation days.